# Error whilst exporting 3D pdf from Global Mapper

Tags: 3d, 3d-model, global-mapper

I’m try to export a 3D PDF from Global Mapper and I’m get this error message:

> Error exporting to 3D PDF file.
>
> Could not create U3D file.
>
> PDF3DOverlay.cpp - 645 Version: v18.2.0 (64-bit)
>
> Build Time: May 24 2017 14:41:24
>
> Thread: Main UI Thread Windows 10 Home (64-bit) Memory: 3,636,162,560 of 8,018,649,088 available, GDI Usage: 425 GDI (Peak 535), 173 User (Peak 328)

The data I’m using is a 69mb .obj file

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I think that only 32bit version Global mapper can export PDF file.

Comment: Really? Well, that's a pain! Cheers anyway!